# Hibernate onetomany Pagination-on-Master BasicType-ElementCollection-Children

Tags: hibernate, pagination, duplicates, one-to-many

Problem:
How to paginate on master and get all the children (for each master)?

The hibernate query should return list of unique master records which is paginated and each master entity should contain all its children (basic type String).

I tried it by defining master as entity and children basic type (String) via ElementCollection
but the query returns duplicate master entities, due to which i am not able to paginate on master. However when i use fetch Lazy i am able to get what i expect :)

Can't it be achieved using eager fetch?
What is best way to achieve it ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any thoughts on the issue ?

Comment: The pagination limit offset is applied on Cartesian product of Parent and Children via ElementCollection Basic Type and NOT on the parent entity.

Answer (score 0):

Criteria  criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Parent.class)
       .setMaxResults(count)
        .setFirstResult(start)
        .setFetchMode("children1", FetchMode.SELECT)
        .setFetchMode("children2", FetchMode.SELECT)
        .setFetchMode("children3", FetchMode.SELECT)
        .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);

```
   return criteria.list();
```